# Insert image into jsp page

Tags: html, jsp

I am sorry that I need to ask this but I already spent three days trying to do this. I am buidling Java Web application and I want to include image to JSP page. Project name is realestates and I have Files folder inside realestates folder.

My code is like this:

```
<img alt="govno" src="<%=request.getContextPath() + "/Files/kurac.jpg"%>" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;">
```

This is what gets generated on page after I open it in browser:

```
<img alt="govno" src="/realestates/Files/kurac.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;">
```

BUT, image is not dispayed, only alt "govno" is written. I have tried many many paths (relative, absolute, changed folder structure million times and whatever I could think of and find on internet but nothing helped). Who would say that such a thing will be so hard to do???

Folder structure on Tomcat server after deployment is:

```
webapps
 - realestates
   |- WEB-INF
   |- Files
     |- kurac.jpg
```

Comment: Without knowing any details, impossible to help. From the browser if you enter in the same path, what happens? The obvious answer is that the image isn't where you think it is.

Comment: I can open it in browser but I need to enter absolute path file:///C://Users//Lazar//Documents//workspace-sts-3.8.3.RELEASE//realestates//Files//kurac.jpg, but as I wrote in the question in the browser I get src="/realestates/Files/kurac.jpg". Is this OK?

Comment: I updated my question. I read that file path can not be somewhere on the OS file system, it has to be somewhere on the server. Before I wasn't even deploying image to the server. I was trying to refer to it from server to somewhere on file system.

Comment: You're using the wrong filename, first of all. Second, depending on how you're deploying, it may just be 'Files/_kurac.jpg'.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but file names are without "_". This sign I just use to represent folder structure. It's like /webapp/realestates/WEB-INF/Files/kurac.jpg.

Comment: If you must use anything, use a hyphen, and separate it from the filename with a space to avoid confusion.

Comment: does anyone have any idea? any idea at all? I am stuck

Comment: hi lijep is it maven project or it's normal dynamic web project, let me know than i will give you proper suggestion.

Comment: hit f12 and check whether the image is loaded or not

Comment: it is Maven project with Spring MVC. When I try to open direct link to image I get 404 error. I don't have anywhere in my controllers any request handling to image link. I have only request handler for JSP page where I want to include the image.

Comment: should I put images somewhere to resources? Does resources have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a guy explaining it in less than a minute.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwjwSYOrnS8

So two things are required:

1.Add this line in some config xml file

```
<mvc:resources location="/files/" mapping="/files/**"></mvc:resources>
```

2.Include image into JSP page with this line

```
 <img src='<c:url value="/files/korali.jpg"></c:url>' />
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you got yourself (and everyone else) confused of where the image is.
From your question, it seems to be at `webapps/realestates/Files/kurac.jpg`, so this should work:

```
<img src="/realestates/Files/kurac.jpg">
```

From your first comment, it is at `C:/Users/Lazar/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.3.RELEASE/realestates/Files/kurac.jpg`, so it will not be accessible via `http://`.
This won't work.

From your later comment, it is at `/webapp/realestates/WEB-INF/Files/kurac.jpg`.
Files inside WEB-INF are not publicly accessible.
This won't work either.

As a last resort, move the image file to `webapps/ROOT` directory.
Try `http://localhost/kurac.jpg` from your browser.
Replace `localhost` with your server hostname as necessary.
If it works, this will work as well:

```
<img src="/kurac.jpg">
```

If it doesn't, there is something wrong with your Tomcat configuration.
Try reinstalling.

Comment: Nothing helped :(

Answer (score 2):

At first you must create image folder outside the `WEB-INF` directory and try that code `<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Files/kurac.jpg"/>`

Comment: also has folder (Named Files) outside the `WEB-INF` see above

Comment: @Asif.Ali try above code it work fine.i also use same code in my project

Comment: @Asif.Ali see https://github.com/developerbinod/OLMS this project .above code work fine in this project

Answer (score 1):

I read your question and i have one solution for your problem you can use the INPUT STREAM for add an image in JSP page...

THIS IS JUST EXAMPLE...AND MAY HAVE ERROR BUT THIS IS THE WAY HOW TO INSERT IMAGE IN JSP...

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
Connection connection = 
    DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "user", "pass");  

psmnt = connection.prepareStatement(
    "insert into save_image(user, image) values(?,?)");  
psmnt.setString(1, username);  

ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("C://image.png")); 
File imageFile = new File("C://image.png");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile);

psmnt.setBinaryStream(2, (InputStream)fis, (fis.length()));
int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: This is not what I need. I just need to display image on page, and that image is on server file system.

Answer (score 0):

Webpage never allows accessing any local files.
This means that if you write `img src="c:\imagesfolder\abc.jpg"` in the jsp file it will not work (it can work only in some editor but it will not work using a browser).

```
img src="http://localhost.8080/imageshow/sendimage/12/abc.jpg" width="100" height="100"
```